# Accessing x-data in a function

Tags: alpine.js

I have the following code:

```
<div class="filter" x-data="filterData()">
    <button @click="test()>Click me</button>
</div>
```

Filter Data

```
window.filterData = () => {
    return {
        section: null,
        options: {
            "one": [],
            "two": [],
            "three": []
        },
        test() {
            console.log(this.options);
        },
    }
}
```

When I click on `test()` all I get back is `Proxy {}` in the console log. What can I do to actually interact with the options data?

Answer (score 0):

The Proxy is the reactive wrapper used by Alpine to track updates but it functions the same as the wrapped value.

In this case if you do `this.options.one.length` you'll get 0.

If you need to inspect the value you can `JSON.stringify()` it